# How to reset storage parameters of a table

Tags: database, postgresql

I have below settings for the table. Instead of using table level setting, I want the table to use SYSTEM / Server level autovacuum settings. Is that possible?

```
# select pg_options_to_table(reloptions) from pg_class where relname='test' ;
          pg_options_to_table
----------------------------------------
 (autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor,0)
 (autovacuum_analyze_threshold,1000000)
 (autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay,0)
 (autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor,0)
 (autovacuum_vacuum_threshold,1000000)
 (autovacuum_enabled,true)
```

Basically it should look like below

```
 select pg_options_to_table(reloptions) from pg_class where relname='test' ;
 pg_options_to_table
---------------------
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The column [`reloptions` of `pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) contains [storage parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS). You can set or reset these parameters using [alter table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html), .e.g:

```
alter table test reset (autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor, autovacuum_analyze_threshold)
```